# Mongo import to Azure Cosmos DB Update incomplete

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have 50000 documents in my Cosmos db collection.
Using mongo shell, I want to remove a field from all documents and when i run the update command. Below is the output.

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 9941, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 9941 })

Seems like update is not applied to all the documents even though all documents contain the field to remove.

If i run update command again few more documents are updated.

Any idea why this is happening. Is there a way to update all documents at once?

Comment: What does the update query look like?

Comment: Update query ---- db.movie_review.update( { reviewTime: { $exists: true } },  { $unset: { reviewTime: 1 } }, false, true );

Comment: @pks I speculate that is because of  ThroughPut setting(RUs), cosmos db can't process so many documents at once. In sql api, it is controlled by Continuation Token,but for Mongo API,i found nothing about that.Maybe you could submit feedback to cosmos db team for more assistance.